# Getting classCastException when upgrade from strom/zookeepr 2.5/3.8.0 to 2.6/3.9.1

Tags: apache-storm, classcastexception

I can't find any channel to connect with Apache storm developer, but we used Apache Storm for our pricing engine for a long time, and currently we are upgrade to Storm latest version 2.6 + zookeeper 3.9.1 along with Java 8 updated to Java17
But we are getting error like this if we restarted only worker without restarting the whole cluster.

Just wondering whether anyone can give me some quick thoughts where I can look into it? Thanks!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException : java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
  at org.apache.storm.tails.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:413)
  at java.base.java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by :  java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
  at org.apache.storm.trident.topology.MasterBatchCoordinator.getStoredCurrTransaction(MasterBatchCoordinator.java:235)
  at org.apache.storm.trident.topology.MasterBatchCoordinator.open(MasterBatchCoordinator.java:87)
```

Tried send problem to email "user@storm.apache.org" based on this link, but got mailer sending failure notice
[https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html#:~:text=Getting%20help,-NOTE%3A%20The%20google%20groups](https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html#:%7E:text=Getting%20help,-NOTE%3A%20The%20google%20groups)